# wordpress meta_query of date of birth and date of death

Tags: wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

How can I retrieve my posts and postmeta with the following two `meta_key => 'date of birth'` and `meta_key => 'date of death'` and its `meta_value => 'YYYYMMDD'`, with compare with current date(Ymd) and month like 29 april or 29/4 or 29-4.

Something like the following:

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$query_args1 = array (
'post_type'      => $post_types,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post__not_in'   => explode(',', $params['exclude']),
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation'       => 'OR',
                array(
                    'meta_key'      => 'date_of_birth',
                    'meta_compare'  => '=',
                    'type'    => 'date',
                    'meta_value'    => $today
                ),
                 array(
                    'meta_key'      => 'date_of_death',
                    'meta_compare'  =>  '=',
                    'type'    => 'date',
                    'meta_value'    => $today
                )
            ),
);
```

Comment: @vyas Is 'date of birth' and 'date of death'  write ? I means it should be date_of_birth and date_of_death.

Comment: @Yatendra Yes that's my meta_key and i want to compare with current date.

Answer (score 0):

I am not try this but I hope it will help you. 
You could try the REGEXP version:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'date_of_birth',
        'value'     => '^hello@',
        'compare'   => 'REGEXP',
    )
)
```

Or follow this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159426/meta-query-with-string-starting-like-pattern

Comment: Sorry @yatendra this one also not working. You understand exactly my question.